# How to render jsx correctly

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jsx

```
<div className="feedback">
    {(this.state.finished) ? questions.map(function(x, index) { return
    <div>
    </div>
    }) : null}
</div>
```

so I have the above code at the moment. I would like to add in another piece of js code like this `this.state.score` but not within the map function as I only want it rendered once (currently it renders every time it maps over the array)

```
<div className="feedback">
    {(this.state.finished) ? {this.state.score} //WANT TO ADD IT HERE questions.map(function(x, index) { return
    <div>
    </div>
    }) : null}
</div>
```

but this doesn't work. so how can I add my code in here in this block? I need it inside the ternary too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary expressions in JSX must return either an array or a single node, similar to how the `render` method of React must return only a single node.

```
<div className="feedback">
    { (this.state.finished) ?
      <div>
        {this.state.score}
        {questions.map(function(x, index) {
          return <div></div>
        })}
      </div>
      :
      null
    }
</div>
```

Now, the ternary results in a single node (a `<div>`) that basically "wraps" all the things you want to conditionally render. Also, note that the `questions.map` is wrapped in curly braces `{}` because you're nesting inline JavaScript inside of JSX inside of even more inline JavaScript.